# Can't connect to Mysql from Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

When i ran cucumber BDD .feature files getting the below mentioned error, but was able to connect through Mysql command line client. Any inputs to solve this will be very much helpful, Thanks.

I am using:

- WinXp (64 bit)
- Mysql 5.1 (64 Bit)
- Ruby 193
- cucumber 0.8.5
- Mysql 2.8.1
- watir 1.6.5 etc.

As Ruby is 32 bit and Mysql is 64 bit used *mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32* to install mysql2.8.1 gem with the ***mysql -v 2.8.1 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=C:mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32***  command.

Exception:

```
@ie
Scenario: Verify that Multiple bookings for the same date is not allowed
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (Mysql::Error)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `real_connect'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `connect'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:75:in `new'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:75:in `mysql_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `block in checkout'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:3166:in `quoted_table_name'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:902:in `delete_all'
C:/CodeBase/war/behavioural_testing/features/support/env.rb:47:in `Before'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `test` db created? does this happens when running the app as well or only on tests?

Comment: Ya, DB created, it happens only on tests.

Comment: Just to be sure `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Comment: can you post your database.yml?